# Ansible condition for comment

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to add a condition before to run a playbook which check if there is a title (my case it is a comment) on the playbook ?

For example :

```
#Changed by Peter
#This playbook is for apache
#version 2.1.1
---
  task:
    xxxxxx
```

And checked if the #Changed by Peter and the rest are on the playbook before to run it
I checked different kind of conditions but nothing works...

cya,

BS

Comment: I'm really wondering why you would ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 2):

There isnt any build-in mechanism, but if i had to do this, i'd first check the yaml file contents and then include the file (or not), for example

```
- name: run peters playbook
  include: test.yml
  when: "{{ lookup('file', 'test.yml').split('\n')[1] == '#Changed by Peter' }}"
```

Before you go ahead and use something like that, i'd question your motives and try to find out a way to not do something like this.